# Paypal- Accept International Payments with DoDirectPayment

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payflowpro, website-payment-pro

I have integrated **DoDirectPayment** api on my website **(U.S)** to accept direct payments from Credit Cards. Recently I have been receiving complaints from some customers from **Italy**, saying they were not able to make payments. And every time they make a payment they receive message saying **'Invalid expiry date'** (*Confirmed!*. *Customers did put a valid expiry date.*), which is quite strange .

I have my own HTML form that accepts, CC number, CVV, Street, Expiry date, City, Zip, Country Code etc.

The product availability of paypal shows **Website Payments Pro** is available only for **U.K, U.S and Canada** https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/howto_product_matrix/. Does this mean people from these countries only can make payments? **If Yes,** what other alternative should I chose to accept payment from any country(that supports paypal). **If Not,** is there any settings I have to change in my merchant account?

Any help is greatly appreciated. If you think I am missing any specifics/ any code/ any other data, please ask.